# TypeError: wrapper.exists is not a function && TypeError: wrapper.find is not a function

Tags: reactjs, testing

I am writing test cases for one of my component which is having router(using withrouter).and i am getting error wrapper.find is not a function.
Basic requirement is need to check the existence of  tag in my render,also check the aria-label attribute of  tag

const Component = () => 
  const WrappedComponent = withRouter(Component)

```
  describe('Error Boundary...', () => {
    it('should render children when no error is encountered', () => {
      const wrapper = ReactTestRenderer.create(
        <Router><WrappedComponent /></Router>
      );
      expect(wrapper.toJSON().type).toEqual('div');
      expect(wrapper.toJSON()find('a').attr('aria-label')).toEqual('Hello World');
    });
  });
```

Comment: When i ran the text am getting Expected = ''Hello World''
and Received= <div className="hh-ns-container mb-hotelHeaderContainer-ns"><div className="mb-hotelHeaderInfo"><h1 className="hotelHeaderInfoText-ns" /></div><div className="hh-actionLinks-ns"><a aria-label="Go back to reservation details" className="uitk-button uitk-button-small uitk-button-secondary mb-seeItinerary-button" href="/" onClick={[Function anonymous]} onTouchStart={[Function anonymous]}><span className="uitk-button-container" /></a></div></div>
which do have <a> tag with attribute aria-label

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling `.toJSON()` in your expect lines.

```
 describe('Error Boundary...', () => {
    it('should render children when no error is encountered', () => {
      const wrapper = ReactTestRenderer.create(
        <Router><WrappedComponent /></Router>
      );
      expect(wrapper.root.type).toEqual('div');
      expect(wrapper.root.find('a').attr('aria-label')).toEqual('Hello World');
    });
  });
```

Comment: still am getting wrapper.find is not a function

Comment: Updated answer (added `wrapper.root`)

Comment: sorry .. am getting TypeError: predicate is not a function

Comment: Yes, I see. You are trying to `find` an element using a CSS selector. Using react test renderer you can only find by instance, type of props: https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#testinstancefind